# How do I find out the GC strategy being used by Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, garbage-collection

When I start up my Tomcat server I have no idea which GC strategy it is using. How do I find it out?

Answer (score 0):

It is using whatever strategy is the default for the version of Java you are using, unless you've changed it within setenv.bat/.sh.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know what is the JVM picking as default for my machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jinfo` utility that comes with the JDK to query the VM flags and system properties at runtime. However it only shows what flags have been explicitly set, it does not show you the default values being used. You have to read your JVM vendor doc to find out what the default values are, since they can vary from one VM implementation to another.

Answer (score 0):

The option that prints out the command line flags used when starting up Tomcat is:

```
-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use "jmap" to determine. For example:

jmap -heap 15290

Attaching to process ID 15290, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 24.55-b03

using thread-local object allocation.
**Parallel GC** with 8 thread(s)
.....

As you can see here it shows Parallel GC policy

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining why you posted that code and what does it do. Also consider taking the time to format your answer to be easily understood by readers.